# What's the Maven Configuration for in Jenkins server?

Tags: maven, jenkins

In Jenkins's "Configure System", there is "Maven Configuration" where you can set the local installation of Maven. What's this for?

local installation means the local Maven installation on the Jenkins server, right? But most of time we build in Slaves.

Jirong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use the Jenkins master only configuration, and it is an option for this situation :)

It works also for slaves, if path is identical as in master.

To configure different path on slaves go to **Manage Jenkins** -> **Manage Nodes** -> *node name* -> **Configure**.

Comment: "It works also for slaves, if path is identical as in master." That's exactly the problem. My Jenkins server is Linux and one Slave is Windows, now the build is complaining can't find the Maven. How to resolve this? Is there a way to set these for each Slave?

Comment: @MariuszS, I couldn't find anything which configures Maven configuration per Slave node. Can you explain specifically what should be next after **Manage Jenkins** -> **Manage Nodes** -> **[node name]** -> **Configure**? You may also find my rather duplicated question here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/28387142/441652