# MVN Package running in cmd but not in Jenkins build

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, tomcat, command-prompt

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/snmTW.png)

As you can see in the pic mvn command in respective directory is showing the result as *"mvn is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file."* [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/izulj.png)

But in the cmd pic you can observe that command is working flawlessly, please help so i may proceed in my course, where am I going wrong ??

Comment: Please embed images correctly

Answer (score 0):

The Jenkins service is run under some user which has some PATH variable. From your pics, it seems, the mentioned user is missing the 'mvn' entry there.

To fix that, you need to configure the Maven Tool in the Jenkins cfg (set MAVEN_HOME), similarly like guys did in [How to configure Maven installation in Jenkins per individual Slave node?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28387142/how-to-configure-maven-installation-in-jenkins-per-individual-slave-node)